# Are iOS apps extractable?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, extract

Are the `.ipa` files in which Apple iOS apps come, in **any** way extractable?

If it can be done, then I don't want to know how to extract it, but only how to protect content when this would happen.

**Example 1:**
*I have a database in my app with 1000+ famous quotes.*
For someone to manually retype it, would seem like a useless waste; but if he could copy it this way, my app's uniqueness could be at stake.

**Example 2:**
*I have raw images in my app, 1000+ images.*
For someone to manually screen-capture it is impossible (in my app's context it is impossible) but if he could extract it, I will be screwed.

Does anyone have any knowledge regarding this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to extract resources from .ipa files. As with anything of this sort, if your application can access the data then it will be possible (with enough work) for someone to extract it.

It all boils down to a cost benefit analysis. If the data is valuable enough to justify the cost of extracting it then someone will likely dedicate the resources to extract it.

Answer (score 3):

An ipa file is just a zip file with a different name; to extract the contents simply rename the file to .zip and open with unarchiver of choice.

Answer (score 3):

`.ipa` files are just zip archives and anyone with a copy can extract their contents.

If you're really concerned about your content you can add various levels of obfuscation but those come with some overhead and since your app needs to be able to read the content eventually you only make it slightly harder for a user to extract a copy of that content.

Answer (score 1):

on a jailbroken iPhone you have root access. Hence you can easily browse the app's folders and access their data.